# What is the purpose of having an instance created inside new method of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

Learning rails from the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), but what is the reason for having an empty article instance in `new`? When you go to new, it just renders a form for you and then when you submit, it creates it with the new instance inside the `create` action. If there are errors, it returns that instance to the new view (form) correct? In the docs, it says the below:

> The reason why we added @article = Article.new in the
>   ArticlesController is that otherwise @article would be nil in our
>   view, and calling @article.errors.any? would throw an error.

But why would `@article` be `nil` if you already have created an instance through the `create` action? Why would the new action need to create another instance that has the errors? Isn't the instance created by `create` with the errors the one that will be rendered in new?

//controller

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails runs only the code inside corresponding action when processing a request. So when user goes to `/articles/new` only `new` action is triggered and when user makes HTTP POST request to `/articles` only `create` action is called. Read rails [guides on ActionController](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions)

Comment: so how does the when the article fails to save, and new is rendered, how do the errors get into the @article from new?

Comment: if `@article.save` returns `false` then `new.html.erb` template is rendered with already defined `@article` instance. I.e. `render "new"` in `create` method does not run `new` method. It just uses its html template to render page

Comment: then when is the `@article` inside new used? when you first visit the page to see the form? what is the purpose of having the `@article` there

Comment: and the comment in the guide says that the `@article` is necessary to hold the error

Comment: yes, `@article` in new is used when user visits `/articles/new` for the first time. It is required to render form properly. Form rendering is described in @sajan answer. After user submits form in the create method article instance is initialized using the params from form and if there are any record errors this instance is used to render form with errors.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in explaining but I will try.
To me, Rails use this way so that we will have to write less code and rails will handle rest of the things.

Here is what you do:
Lets assume, your Article model has 2 attributes(columns) i.e title, text.

Controller:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

So when you do this, rails knows that you are generating a form for `@article` which is a (empty) object of `Article` class.

So it generates appropriate HTML from the from helpers like 
`<%= f.text_field :title %>` with proper `id` and `name` so that it can be mapped later in `create` action.

You don't have a `title` attribute in model then it will throw an error. So you can not do like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :body %>
```

Because rails knows, this form is for `Article` and your article does not have any attribute(column) for `body`.

when the form generates, it does not have any idea about your `create` action. It knows about `new` action only.

So this is one of the reason behind initializing a `new` record for form.

I hope you got my point. Maybe someone else can explain better with any other reason behind this.